# Return column headers based on value in table

Tags: excel

I have a table that has both column headers and row titles. Each cell in the matrix can be empty or not. The actual value is inconsequential. My goal is to look at each row by title and return an array of column headers for which the intersecting cell is not empty.

```
Titles    Col_A    Col_B    Col_C    ...
Row_1                x
Row_2       x                 x
Row_3       x
```

If interested in `Row_1`, I should return `{Col_B}`, or if searching `Row_2` then I should return `{Col_A, Col_C}`.
I have the following formula that return an array of cell values for non-empty cells, but I do not know how to get the column headers from this.

```
=FILTER(XLOOKUP(A2,OtherSheet!A:A,OtherSheet!B:O,""),NOT(ISBLANK(XLOOKUP(A2,OtherSheet!A:A,OtherSheet!B:O,""))))
```

So using the above example, if `A2=Row_1`, the formula above would return `{x}`, or if `A2=Row_2`, `{x,x}`.

Because I know this table is limited to single values (`"FOO"`) I have also tried the formula

```
XLOOKUP("FOO",XLOOKUP(A2,OtherSheet!$A$1:$A$31,OtherSheet!B$2:$O$32),OtherSheet!B$1:$O$1)
```

Which for `A2=Row_2` returns `Col_A` alone rather than an array of all matching values.

If I give the outer XLOOKUP as the first parameter an array (`{"FOO","FOO",...}`) it simply returns the same length array with all values being `Col_A`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way:-

```
=FILTER(B1:D1,ISBLANK(INDEX(B2:D4,MATCH("Row_2",A2:A4,0),0))=FALSE,FALSE)
```

The formula is tested on your sample and shows the way to construct a solution. I think you'll be able to make the final adjustments. However, I had a little trouble with it from which I learned that the number of columns in the INDEX and the FILTER must be identical.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks. Maybe cleaner to not use `=FALSE` since `ISBLANK()` is already boolean and can be wrapped in `NOT()`.

Answer (score 2):

This formula returns not an array, but a comma separated list of titles. The text value in the grid can be anything.

[image]

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(ISBLANK(INDEX(B2:B6,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$6,0)):INDEX($D$2:$D$6,MATCH(F2,$A$2:$A$6,0))),"",$B$1:$D$1))
```

Comment: This is clever, but I really need an array rather than a string of text for this use case.